# Terraform: How to remove a user resource created from an array/list?

Tags: terraform

I have a file `users.tf` file that creates the admin users for aws. It does so by defining a list (e.g. `users = ["bob", "john", "tom"]`)

and then iterating over them with the `aws_iam_user` resource using the `count` functionality in terraform, like so:

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "user" {
  count = length(local.users)
  name  = local.users[count.index]
}
```

the issue here, is that if I remove the first element of the array ("bob" from the above example), what terraform will suggest to do after issuing `terraform plan`, instead of deleting bob, is to change bob to john, change john to tom, and delete tom.

like so:

```
  # aws_iam_user.user[0] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_iam_user" "user" {
        arn           = "arn:aws:iam::5555555:user/bob"
        force_destroy = false
        id            = "bob"
      ~ name          = "bob" -> "john"
        path          = "/"
        tags          = {}
        unique_id     = "BLABLABLA11111"
    }

  # aws_iam_user.user[1] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_iam_user" "user" {
        arn           = "arn:aws:iam::5555555:user/john"
        force_destroy = false
        id            = "john"
      ~ name          = "john" -> "tom"
        path          = "/"
        tags          = {}
        unique_id     = "BLABLABLA22222"
    }

  # aws_iam_user.user[2] will be destroyed
  - resource "aws_iam_user" "user" {
      - arn           = "arn:aws:iam::5555555:user/tom" -> null
      - force_destroy = false -> null
      - id            = "tom" -> null
      - name          = "tom" -> null
      - path          = "/" -> null
      - tags          = {} -> null
      - unique_id     = "BLABLABLA3333" -> null
```

this will result in john getting the arn of bob, and tom getting the arn of john. which is undesirable.

I tried using the [very new feature](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/pull/21922) (released 19 hours prior to the writing of this question) of for_each loop instead of count, and defining the keys as the original index numbers, hoping that terraform will consider them as the same resource.

yeah well, no such luck:

```
...
# aws_iam_user.user[1] will be destroyed
...
# aws_iam_user.user["1"] will be created
...
```

**I will summarize my question:**

Is there any way to delete a resource (specifically `aws_iam_user`), when that resource was created by iterating over a list, such that all the remaining resources stay the way they were?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you have seen here is the situation that [the `count` documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count) warns about in its final paragraph:

> Note that the separate resource instances created by `count` are still identified by their *index*, and not by the string values in the given list. This means that if an element is removed from the middle of the list, all of the indexed instances *after* it will see their subnet_id values change, which will cause more remote object changes than were probably intended. The practice of generating multiple instances from lists should be used sparingly, and with due care given to what will happen if the list is changed later.

Fortunately, this is the very problem the `for_each` feature is intended to solve. Though, in order to use it effectively it's important to choose meaningful unique keys in the map you pass to `for_each`:

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "user" {
  for_each = { for name in local.users : name => name }

  name  = each.value
}
```

This will cause Terraform to track instance identifiers like `aws_iam_user.user["john"]` rather than `aws_iam_user.user[1]`.

You have existing `count`-based instances in your state though, so it'll take some migration steps to get there. Unfortunately Terraform doesn't have enough information to automatically correlate your existing index-based addresses with the new name-based ones, but by using your existing list with a separate one-off script you can tell Terraform how to translate these by running a command like this for each entry in the list:

```
terraform state mv 'aws_iam_user.user[1]' 'aws_iam_user.user["john"]'
```

After that, Terraform will track these objects by name and thus adding and removing names will affect only the objects relating to the names you changed.

---

If you aren't ready to do a full switch to `for_each` right now, you can use a similar strategy with a one-off script to "heal" the hole created by removing an item from your list:

```
# First, Terraform must "forget" the user that you removed
terraform state rm 'aws_iam_user.user[0]'

# Then renumber the subsequent items to correlate with their new
# positions in the list.
terraform state mv 'aws_iam_user.user[1]' 'aws_iam_user.user[0]'
terraform state mv 'aws_iam_user.user[2]' 'aws_iam_user.user[1]'
# etc, etc
```

This will of course be a rather tedious, error-prone process to do manually if you have more than a small number of users, so better to write a small program to generate the script.